# How to attach storage volume with elasticsearch nodes in kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I am doing setup of Elasticseach on Kubernetes. I have created the cluster of Elasticsearch of 2 nodes. I want to attach storage with both of these nodes. like 80Gi with the first node and 100Gi with the second node. 
My Kubernetes cluster is on EC2 and I am using EBS as storage.

Answer (score 0):

In order to attach persistence, you need:

- A StorageClass Object (Define the Storage)
- A PersistentVolume Object (Provision the Storage)
- A PersistentVolumeClaim Object (Attach the storage)

With each Node in ElasticSearch that you can attached with the pods in deployment\pod object definition.

An easier way is deploying ES cluster using [Helm Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch).

Answer (score 0):

As per helm chart documentation:

> Automated testing of this chart is currently only run against GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine). If you are using a different Kubernetes provider you will likely need to adjust the `storageClassName` in the `volumeClaimTemplate`

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: elast
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  fsType: ext4
```

Hope this help.